# How to include graphics from parent directory using \graphicspath?

Tags: graphics, texlive, miktex

To include graphics from parent directory I am using

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../pop/}{../graph/}}
```

This works fine for MiKTeX but seems to fail for TeX live installed on the same computer (compiler did not find graphics files).

**What I'm doing wrong?** The directories `PoP` and `Graph` are located on the same level as the working directory with the source LaTeX file.

Update: Directory structure (for test purposes I put same graphics files in PoP and Graph subdirecrtories)

```
ECRH 
|- OS2012
|  |- ECRH(proc).tex
|- PoP
|  |- ECRH-Fig1.pdf
|  |- ECRH-Fig2.pdf
|  |- ...
|- Graph
   |- ECRH-Fig1.pdf
   |- ECRH-Fig2.pdf
   |- ...
```

Comment: Are the directory names correctly capitalized?

Comment: @egreg: I tried `\graphicspath{{../PoP/}{../Graph/}{../eps/}}` with the same results.

Comment: Can you please add a scheme of what you have?

Comment: @egreg: please see update.

Comment: On my system it works (`<use ../PoP/pop.pdf>` is one of the messages). But it's not Windows.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

check your security settings in texmf.cnf  access to `../` may be turned off. My (default) TL2012 installation allows them for reading:

```
% Allow TeX \openin, \openout, or \input on filenames starting with `.'
% (e.g., .rhosts) or outside the current tree (e.g., /etc/passwd)?
% a (any)        : any file can be opened.
% r (restricted) : disallow opening "dotfiles".
% p (paranoid)   : as `r' and disallow going to parent directories, and
%                  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.
openout_any = p
openin_any = a
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I've checked texmf.cnf, both global and local.