# Change path of where tikz externalization saves the pdf and eps

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, eps, tikz-external

I am using the TikZ externalization to speed up the compilation process and to have the eps files for the admission of the article which I'm writing.

So I have lines like

```
\begin{figure}
    \input{../path/filename.tex}
\end{figure}
```

, which I want to replace with

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{../path/filename.eps}
\end{figure}
```

when I submit my article. The problem is that the TikZ externalization changes both 'path' and 'filename', so that I would have to use

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{some_other_filename.eps}
\end{figure}
```

when I use

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";pdftops -eps "\image".pdf;}}
\tikzexternalize
```

in the preamble of the document. I do not know yet how to make a bash script to process this change, but it would already be easier if the original path and filename would be maintained.

UPDATE.
I just found in the PGFplots manual that one can change the filename with the command

```
\begin{figure}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{path/nameyouchoose}
    \input{../path/filename.tex}
\end{figure}
```

However, it seems impossible to use a relative path, something like

```
\begin{figure}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{../path/nameyouchoose}
    \input{../path/filename.tex}
\end{figure}
```

How can I use a relative path?

Comment: Is it related to [how-to-include-graphics-from-parent-directory-using-graphicspath](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63693/how-to-include-graphics-from-parent-directory-using-graphicspath)?

Comment: No, I don't think it is, as \graphicspath{} is for where picture are sought when using the \includegraphics{} command, not when using the \input{} command, as I do :(.

Comment: Can you use `\tikzexternalize[prefix=../path/]`, and `\tikzsetnextfilename{figure}` instead of `\tikzsetnextfilename{../path/figure}`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No that does not work either.

Comment: @Adriaan Very old question, which could be solved with:  Does [Question regarding pgfplots externalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398790/124842), [TexStudio output-directory and tikzexternalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360820/124842) or [Error using tikz externalize: can't write md5 file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243935/124842)