# Error using tikz externalize: can't write md5 file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I tried to use the externalize library. It worked fine when all my files where located in the same folder. Usually I am using a subfolder as build folder, where all generated files should be stored. Setting this up with the prefix for externalize, I get an error message that seems to me weird.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a MWE that throws the error message **! I can't write on file `build/Test-figure0.md5'**

I am using TexStudio and Texlive 2014. To compile I use the command:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -output-directory=build %.tex
```

Here is a not working example:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzset{external/up to date check={md5}}
\tikzset{external/mode=convert with system call} 
\tikzexternalize 
\tikzsetexternalprefix{build/}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzstyle{myedgestyle} = [diamond-open diamond]
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (v2) at (2,4) {};
\node (v1) at (-0.5,2) {};
\draw [diamond-open diamond] (v1) edge (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Until now I tried the following things:

1. Try to run it without the prefix

*It works, but all the files will be created in the main folder*

2. Using \tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -output-directory=build -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}} without the prefix option to change the build location

*It creates the pictures in the build directory but I will get this error: ===== Image 'Test-figure0' is up-to-date. ====== !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file Test-figure0.pdf): cannot find image file ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! –*

3. Using the former \tikzset and the prefix option together *I will get the md5 massage again, if the picture wasn't created before. If I am not using the prefix option within the first run, the picture will be created in the build folder. Switching the prefix option back on in a second run it will generate no errors and use the previously generated pictures.*

I think that this is a pretty dirty workaround. Is there a better solution?

4. Changing the folder for the tikz pictures *does not make any difference.*
5. Runing the example in draft mode and tikzset and prefix set *will run with no errors, but the pictureboxes have a standard size.*

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Have you tried not setting the prefix at all? You are already outputting to `build/`. Do you need the prefix as well?

Comment: Yes, I did that and if I am not using the prefix it works but all the picture are created in the main folder.

Comment: For some reason tikz wants to create the .md5 file inside build/build/.
If you create that sub folder, it should work.

Comment: @JonasNyrup I guess it concatenates the `build` directory and the `prefix`. That's why I thought maybe just not using `prefix` at all might work. Interesting that it works with `build/build/` but if you use no `prefix` it won't use `build/` correctly....

Comment: @JonasNyrup Thanks for your advise. It is working and it is a little bit more convenient then before. Might that be a bug within externalize?

Comment: I've run into this issue a few times. Calling pdflatex with `-output-directory=build` essentially recreates your file/folder tree within the output directory. If you include a chapter in your main tex file, say `\include{chapters/chapter1}`, the aux file will be placed in `build/chapters/chapter1.aux`. If the chapters subdirectory does not exist, compilation fails. I've not found a way around this with tikzexternalize[list and make], the .figlist produced here does not obey `output-directory`.

Comment: To sum it up... there is a good workaround but the question whether the problem is a bug or a feature is unsolved.

Comment: I would recommend using https://ctan.org/pkg/memoize or https://ctan.org/pkg/robust-externalize; both are leagues better than tikzexternalize.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your issue occurs because you are using the flag `-output-directory=build` when running `pdflatex`.

---

In order to makes explanations less ambiguous, let's rename  folders:

- you are using the flag `-output-directory=foo`;
- your `.tex` file is in a folder named `root`;
- you are using following macro in your `.tex` file: `\tikzexternalize[prefix=bar/]`.

What happens is that the externalization creates `.pdf` (as well as `.log` and `.dpth` files) in the folder `root/bar/`. However, the **externalization also creates *"output files"*** (actually `.md5`) and thus stores them into... `root/`**`foo/`**`bar`.

The error is raised because the folder `root/foo/bar` doesn't exist on your computer (you only have created `root/bar`). Creating it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
\tikzexternalize[prefix=build/] %  activates folder access folderName=build
```

And:

```
\tikzsetnextfilename{TestFigure} % filename = TestFigure
```

My solution is this:

1. Compile Command:

   pdflatex -shell-escape tikzImageCreate

2.tikzImageCreate.tex: (The .tex file name have to be the same like in the command above (see1.)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%compile with: pdflatex -shell-escape tikzImageCreate

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}

% storage location
\tikzexternalize[prefix=build/] %  your external folderName= build
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\begin{document}
%filename of the tikz fig.,
\tikzsetnextfilename{TestFigure} % your name for the tikz fig.for example filename=TestFigure
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (v2) at (2,4) {};
\node (v1) at (-0.5,2) {};
\draw (v1) edge (v2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```