# Tikz externalize prefix argument combined with -output-directory gives inconsistent behavior

Tags: tikz-external

**Situation**

I am compiling a document using the TikZ externalize library, and want to create my output in an output folder `/out/`, but have the TikZ externalize figures stored in a subfolder `/out/figures/`. The `/out/` folder is specified by passing the `-output-directory=[path to main.tex]/out` argument to pdfLatex, and the `/out/figures/` folder is specified using `\tikzexternalize[prefix=out/figures/]`.

**Expected behavior**

All externalized files are created in the `/out/figures/` folder.

**Actual behavior**

The `figure.md5` file is created in the `/out/out/figures/` folder, whereas all other externalized files are created in the `/out/figures/` folder.

**MWE**

Run the following command:

```
pdflatex -output-directory=[path to main]/out -shell-escape main.tex
```

where `main.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=out/figures/]

\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\getabspath{\jobname.log}

% Avoid having to create these folders manually
\IfFileExists{"\theabsdir out"}{}{\immediate\write18{mkdir "out"}}
\IfFileExists{"\theabsdir out/figures"}{}{\immediate\write18{mkdir "out/figures"}}
\IfFileExists{"\theabsdir out/out"}{}{\immediate\write18{mkdir "out/out"}}
\IfFileExists{"\theabsdir out/out/figures"}{}{\immediate\write18{mkdir "out/out/figures"}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
        \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
        \draw[color=red] plot[id=x] function{x}
        node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to make TikZ externalize create all externalized files in the same folder? Why is the prefix interpreted inconsistently by tikz externalize?

Comment: Related [pgfplots - Error using tikz externalize: can't write md5 file - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243935/error-using-tikz-externalize-cant-write-md5-file?noredirect=1&lq=1). It unfortunately only give a workaround to avoid the error, not actually fix the behavior. (although I guess providing absolute path to `prefix` might fix the issue)

Comment: that is one of the reasons why I never use `-output-directory`. It gets rather difficult to sort out where you actually are and where files are searched and created.

Comment: To be fair there *are* ways to implement the package such that output directory works correctly [shell escape - In Luatex, how to know effective output directory? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388326/in-luatex-how-to-know-effective-output-directory) , the packages just don't implement it.

Comment: @user202729 you're right that providing an absolute path to `prefix` is a way to fix it, but getting the absolute path in Latex using `currfile` does not work great, and hardcoding it is not an option when sharing the Latex code.

Comment: One option is to tell the other people to not use output directory. currfile needs recorder option. As for the "does not work great" part there might be issue with slash/backslash difference & expansion issue; you can ask that instead

Comment: Side node, write18 fails in lualatex, use shellescape package for portability